# Fastest Way to Draw a Static Image in Java

Tags: java, swing, opengl, graphics, processing

I'm in the process of writing a custom heatmap generator. I'm wondering what the fastest way is to draw boxes (up to around 1 million) in Java. Most questions I've found have concentrated on dynamic images (like in games), and I'm wondering if there's a better way to go for static images. I've tried using swing (via a GridLayout and adding a colored canvas to each box), drawing directly on the panel with Graphics2D, and also by using the Processing libraries. While Processing is pretty fast and generates a clean image, the window seems to have problems keeping it; it generates different parts of the image whenever you minimize, move the windows, etc.

I've heard of OpenGL, but I've never touched it, and I wanted some feedback as to whether that (or something else) would be a better approach before investing time in it.

Comment: hard to answer. I bet one of the first answers will contain: "benchmark". However, Graphics2D should be okay. There's even an OpenGL pipeline for Graphics2D you could use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For static images, I paint them to a BufferedImage (BI) and then draw that via Graphics2D.
I keep a boolean that tells me whether the BI is up to date. That way I only incur the expensive painting cost once. If you want to get fancy, you can scale the BI to handle minor resizing. For a major resizing you'll probably want to repaint the BI so as not to introduce artifacts. It's also useful for overlaying data (such as cross hairs, the value under the cursor, etc) as you're only painting the BI and the data.

Comment: I'm not interested in resizing and all that, just in getting my time down so it's about as fast a R (which can do about 6.5 million points in 25-ish seconds). This is pretty good - not quite as fast as I wanted, but definitely faster than what I've been doing. :)